# Sort in descending order

Tags: javascript

I got a script from GitHub but its random: https://github.com/dcbriccetti/name-picker

I tried editing the picker.js at static shuffle(a).

I wan't it in Ascending Order or Descending Order or some option to make it not random, i want set it by myself.

Here the picker.js code:

```
class Picker {
    constructor() {
        this.speech = window.speechSynthesis;
        this.utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        this.cardSpace = [];

        $('#start').click(() => {
            const maxCalls = $('#max-calls').val();
            const names = $('#names').val().split('\n');
            this.cardSpace = [];
            names.map(name => name.trim()).filter(name => name.length > 0).forEach(name => {
                for (let i = 0; i < maxCalls; ++i) {
                    this.cardSpace.push(new NameCard(name));
                }
            });
            Picker.shuffle(this.cardSpace);
        });

        $('#pick').click(() => {
            this.cardSpace = this.cardSpace.filter(card => card.state === card.States.NORMAL);
            if (this.cardSpace.length) {
                const chosenIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.cardSpace.length);
                const card = this.cardSpace[chosenIndex];
                card.pick();
                $('#chosen').text(card.name);
                if ($('#speak').prop('checked')) {
                    this.utterance.text = card.name;
                    this.speech.speak(this.utterance);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    static shuffle(a) {
        for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @KevinHe: I don't think so.  As I read it, the question is just looking for fixed sorts rather than randomly shuffling.

Comment: @KevinHe that's not a duplicate, he's asking about sorting instead of using random order.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort ascending or descending, you need to have a comparator function that returns a 1, 0, or -1 based on comparing two names at a time.  You then give that to the `.sort()` method of your array. [MDN Docs on Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

For example, instead of calling `Picker.shuffle()` in your code,  you might consider calling `this.cardSpace.sort(comparer)`, where comparer looks like this:

```
function comparer(a, b) {
  var nameA = a.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
}
```

That'll sort ascending (so b comes after a).  If you want to sort descending, you can just multiply the return value by -1 (based on a variable or setting, for example).

Answer (score 0):

To have it in default order, instead of random, comment out this line:

```
 Picker.shuffle(this.cardSpace);
```

To then take fine control, simply take control of the order that items are added to cardSpace (that is what the `this.cardSpace.push(new NameCard(name));` line is doing).

To have it in reverse order, replace that `Picker.shuffle` line with:

```
 this.cardSpace.reverse()
```

(See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Comment: Commenting `Picker.shuffle(this.cardSpace);` with _//_ it's not make it default order, it's still random. replace with  `this.cardSpace.reverse()` is same, still random

Comment: @MUHAMMADNAUFALAZKIA You have an `id="names"` div or span in your web page? The order they are listed there should be the default order. Each one is being added `max-calls` times; you probably want to set that to 1 if not using random shuffling.